# Как подключить клиент к серверу через cloudflare

Tags: c#, сервер, сеть, dns, домен

Есть клиент-север, есть прога для тестирования соединения, есть домен через cloudflare, но если добавить srv запись _myserver._tcp.domen.name. SRV 0 5 30777 domen.name., то подключиться через domen.name:30777 не получается. Где я не прав, и  что нужно прочитать?

Comment: Почему srv-запись? Вроде нужно добавлять A-запись для хостов.

Comment: A-запись для самого домена, перенаправляющая на IPv4 есть, но мне нужно получить конкретный порт из-под CloudFlare, в интернете наткнулся на SRV запись.

Comment: Не знаю как работает cloudFlare, вы уверены, что наличие srv записи в вашем домене хоть что то меняет ? Сам порт на любом сервере дложна обслуживать некая запущенная на нем программа. Не вижу причин по которым бы cloudFlare должна что либо запускать на каком либо порту просто из за наличия записи в DNS. В DNS записи же не содержится никакой информации о том, что именно должно быть на указанном порту. Думаю такие вещи должны делаться как минимум в какой нибудь панели управления

Comment: Просто добавляете A-запись и вырубаете на ней обслуживание CloudFlare (там есть специальная кнопка у каждой записи). Все, дальше спокойно через эту запись подключаетесь к серверу.

Comment: А если вам нужна защита для этого приложение (скрытие реального ip и тд), то это скорей всего [Spectrum](https://developers.cloudflare.com/spectrum/getting-started/), но учтите, он платный и доступен для Enterprise плана!

Comment: Есть ли альтернативы Spectrum от CloudFlare?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно оплатить Enterprise план для доступа к Spectrum.
Если же скрытие IP не требуется, достаточно будет создать субдомен, и отключить для него CloudFlare.

Спасибо [EvgeniyZ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220553/evgeniyz) за комментарии!